# how to remove space and replace forward slash in php

Tags: php, replace, space

i have variable

```
$var = "A/P/ 20014/03 /12/4098 "
```

space uncertain in variable how to remove space and replace forward slash. 
i want result like this "A-P-20014-03-12-4098"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple `str_replace` can do this:

```
$var = "A/P/ 20014/03 /12/4098 ";
$var = str_replace(array('/', ' '), array('-', ''), $var);
echo $var;
```

Illustration:

```
                        search for        replacement
$var = str_replace(array('/', ' '), array('-', ''), $var);
                          ^    ^           ^    ^
                          |----|-----------|    |
                               |----------------|
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$var = "A/P/ 20014/03 /12/4098 ";
// / to -
$var = preg_replace("/\//",'-',$var);
// removes all the whitespaces
$var = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $var);
echo $var;
```

Comment: sidenote: you could also do `$var = preg_replace(array("/\//", '/\s+/'), array('-', ''),$var);`

Comment: @Ghost I saw all of your posts + I knew that. Just done it as 2 steps so it's clear for the OP. Thank you anyway!

Comment: just supplemental info, your answers correct too, no prob man

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "A/P/ 20014/03 /12/4098 ";    // your string
$out = str_replace("/", "-", $var);  // replace all / with -
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $out);  // trim all white spaces
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to how this answers the question please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$var = str_replace(array(" ","/"), array("","-"), $var);
```

It's possible to add a a array to str_replace with the chars/strings you want to replace.

If you want to replace more characters you can just add it to the arrays